# VBA - Split digit to a specific length & split up into 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, split, advanced-filter

I'm working on a tool in which a specific table is filtered, output to another sheet, and submit it to word. The filtered part is given and submitting it to word too. That's for the introduction.

Target Now: Specify the filtered data by splitting up the digit number into two parts and submit one part to the attached column.

Code for filter:

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
    Unique:=True
          
dws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Set rng = dws.Range("A1", dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))


rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
With rng.Borders()
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

End Sub
```

the result is:

[image]

(thanks to the cooperation within this forum)

Now I want to split up Column A by its digits. This means every row with a minimum digit length of 4 numbers (last 4 digits) shall be split up and transfer to the close-fitting column. The "rest" shall remain in column A iF there is a length of the last 4 digits to submit to column B.

Example:

1. Cell(2,A) = is blank 'no need for that
2. Cell(3,A) = 1 'no need for that, it shall not be shown anymore
3. Cell(6,A) = 40218 ' this shall be split into 4 remaining in column
   A, and 0218 transferred to column B

**Fact is, always the last 4 digits shall be submitted to the next Column and if there are 4 digits, the
"rest" in front of these 4 digits shall remain in column A.**

Comment: Should what you're asking, happen after the `AdvancedFilter Copy` and all the formatting in the destination worksheet? What if there are (will there be) more than 7 digits?

Comment: @VBasic2008 if first the filter or first the split up happens doesnt matter. But in best case both happens via one macro. Thanks a lot for your time and thoughts! If there will be more than 7 digits? Lets make it pracitical 0110333, important are always the 4 last digits. Thats why in my understanding it shouldnt be important how many digits are there in total  (?) ..in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

### Split by Number of Chars

- You may want to apply the formatting after the split.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    
    Const Chars As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
          
    dws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Dim rng As Range:
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    With rng.Borders()
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    splitByChars rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1), Chars
    
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

End Sub

Sub splitByChars( _
        ByRef rg As Range, _
        ByVal Chars As Long)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = 1
    
    Dim cSize As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim iLen As Long, fLen As Long, rLen As Long
    Dim iString As String, rString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        iString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        iLen = Len(iString)
        If iLen >= Chars Then
            fLen = iLen Mod Chars
            Data(r, 1) = Left(iString, fLen)
            rLen = iLen - fLen
            cSize = rLen / Chars + 1
            rString = Mid(iString, fLen + 1, rLen)
            If cSize > cCount Then
                cCount = cSize
                ReDim Preserve Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cSize)
            End If
            For c = 2 To cSize
                Data(r, c) = Mid(rString, (c - 2) * Chars + 1, Chars)
                Debug.Print r, c, Data(r, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    
    With rg.Resize(, cCount)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Data
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks again :) but like this it seems to be problem to run the code via macro by using a button because the Sub contains paramters. This is at least what i could find out..do you know how to handle this? For now i can not run the code

Comment: The first procedure is your procedure slightly modified. When you run it, near the end, with the line `splitByChars rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1), Chars` it will call the second procedure and do the transformation and continue with `ActieWindow.DisplayGridlines = False`. The range affected by the second procedure is `rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)`, which is, in this case, the range `A2:A7`.

Comment: Do confirm if you want a standalone version, that would be applicable to the range `A2:ALastRow`. it's no big change.

Comment: ah i got it, thanks @VBasic2008 it works! We came already closer to the "perfect" solution. I would like think about by myself (i have to learn) if i can handle it if not i would appreciate if we both could rethink it. Right now it submits to column A digits, even if there are no 4 digits from the right side. Means in this rows there is no input in column B

Comment: If you want an empty string in column `A` when there are fewer than 4 chars, you can add an `Else` statement after `Next c` and in the next line do `Data(r, 1) = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @VBasic2008

I developed the following further now

- change name "Produkthierachie" to "Produktgruppe"
- enter Cell.Value(1,2) on the active sheet to "Serie"
- frame also column B by Line
- delete all rows in between

[image]

What i would like to achieve now is to join all items in column B "Serie" to one cell splitted by a comma IF the serie owns the same Produktgruppe "Product Group".

[image]

That should be possible with a If branch or a do loop or?

```
Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    
    Const Chars As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("export")
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    
    sws.Range("C:C").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("A:A"), _
        Unique:=True
          
    dws.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Dim rng As Range:
    Set rng = dws.Range("A1:B1", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    rng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    
    
    With rng.Borders()
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
        
    End With
    
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Produktgruppe"
    Cells(1, 2).Value = "Serie"

    splitByChars rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1), Chars
    
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

    End Sub

    Sub splitByChars( _
        ByRef rg As Range, _
        ByVal Chars As Long)
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = 1
    
    Dim cSize As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim iLen As Long, fLen As Long, rLen As Long
    Dim iString As String, rString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        iString = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        iLen = Len(iString)
        If iLen >= Chars Then
            fLen = iLen Mod Chars
            Data(r, 1) = Left(iString, fLen)
            rLen = iLen - fLen
            cSize = rLen / Chars + 1
            rString = Mid(iString, fLen + 1, rLen)
            If cSize > cCount Then
                cCount = cSize
                ReDim Preserve Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cSize)
            End If
            For c = 2 To cSize
                Data(r, c) = Mid(rString, (c - 2) * Chars + 1, Chars)
                Debug.Print r, c, Data(r, c)
            Next c
            
            Else
            Data(r, 1) = ""
            
        End If
    Next r
    
    With rg.Resize(, cCount)
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = Data
    End With
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
     With rg
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
     End With

End Sub
```